# Region bounded by a Polar Curve

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

For a National Board Exam:

> Find the area of the region bounded by a polar curve $r^2 = a^2 \cos(2\theta)$

Answer = $a^2$.

So I cheated a bit and plotted the curve on wolfram so i could visualize things quickly: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%5E2+%3D+5%5E2+cos%282theta%29 . Saw this infinity symbol type shape so I decided to set the limits to 0 and pi/2 and just multiply it by 4 from there.

$${ A = \int^b_a \frac{1}{2} f(\theta)^2 d\theta }$$

Put this on my calculator, I get wrong answer but its in the choices...

$${ A = 4\int^{\pi /2}_{0} \frac{1}{2} a^2cos({2\theta}) d\theta = 2a^2}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\cos(2\pi)$ or $\cos(2\theta)$?

Comment: Do you have a typo, i.e. is the curve $r^2=a^2\cos{2\theta}$?

Comment: You need to  integrate $\frac{a^2}{2}\cos(2\theta)$ from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi/4$. Then multiply by $4$.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza whoops sorry typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

note that the part of the curve in the first quadrant is given by:
$$
r=\sqrt{a^2 \cos 2 \theta} \quad for \quad 0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
(for $\frac{\pi}{4}<\theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\cos 2\theta <0$)

so the area is:
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}r^2(\theta)d \theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}a^2 \cos (2\theta)d \theta
$$
that you can easily calculate.

Comment: how do i know if i should use pi/4 or any other correct limit? @emilio-novati

Comment: I don't know a simple general rule. You have to study the function and in your case we see easily that $r(0)=a$ and $r(\pi/4)$=0$.